# Contraction Mapping, Metric

Tags: metric-spaces

Let $X$ = {all continuous functions $f$:[0,1] $\rightarrow$ [0,1]} and let $d$ be the metric on $X$ given by $d$($f$,$g$)= $sup_{t\in[0,1]}$ |$f$($t$)-$g$($t$)| for $f$,$g$ $\in$ $X$

Show that $A$={$f$$\in$$X$: $f$(0)=o and $f$($1$)=$1$} is closed in ($X$,d)

Consider the map $\varphi$ :A $\rightarrow$ $A$ given by $\varphi$ ($f$)=$\tilde{f}$ where for $t$ $\in$[0,1], we define

$\tilde{f} (t$) = 
$\lgroup$ $f/2(3t)$ if $0\leq$t$<$ $1/3$

=$1/2$ if $1/3 \leq$t$ \leq 2/3$

=$1/2+$f$/2(3$t$-2)$ if $2/3$$<$$t$$\leq$$1$

Prove that $\varphi$ is a well defined contraction map on ($A$,$d_{A}$) where $d_{A}$ is the restriction of d to $A$ x $A$.

Deduce that there is a unique function $h$ $\in$$A$ so that $\tilde{h}$=$h$

I am having real difficulty with these few questions. Any help would be appreciated!Also sorry if my Latex is not very fluent. I am relatively new to using it!

Comment: I would show that the complement of $A$ is open. I believe that is easier. Take a function $g\notin A$, and show that there is an open ball around $g$ that doesn't intersect $A$.

Comment: is that enough? or maybe I should try show continuity like @Rasmus said.

Answer (score 1):

For the first questions, notice that $A$ is the intersection of $\mathrm{ev}_0(\{0\})$ and $\mathrm{ev}_1(\{1\})$, where $\mathrm{ev}_x\colon X\to [0,1]$ is evluation at $x$. Can you show that $\mathrm{ev}_x$ is continuous?

For the second part, one can easily show that $d(\tilde f,\tilde g)=d(f,g)/2$. The last claim then follows from the [Banach fixed-point theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: how does one show this easily for the second part?

Comment: Just plug in the definitions of $d$ and $\tilde{}$ in $d(\tilde f,\tilde g)$ and see what you get!